# Was ist die Bedeutung des Wortes "Mail"?

Tags: meaning

Was ist die Bedeutung des Wortes **Mail**? Ist es dasselbe wie **Post** oder eher wie **E-Mail**?

Meine Frage beschäftigt sich mit formeller Sprache, und nicht mit Umgangssprache. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie ich eine Bemerkung verstehen soll, dass etwas per Mail versandt werden soll.

Comment: Es soll per E-Mail versandt werden.

Comment: I corrected your German. Some sentences and constructions are still unusual in German, but I left them as they were because they are okay and hard to translate literally.

Comment: General reference: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mail)

Comment: In formeller Sprache würde ich auf _Mail_ verzichten und auf _E-Mail_ ausweichen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Als deutsches Wort wird „Mail“ synonym zu „E-Mail“ verwandt.

Die deutsche Übersetzung des englischen Wortes „Mail“ lautet „Post“.

Vergleiche: http://www.dict.cc/?s=mail

Comment: K. Stm.: M.E. ist die Verwendung von "Mail" im Deutschen gerade nicht leicht nachschlagbar. Leo hat das Wort beispielsweise nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Tatsächlich. Aber ähnliche Erfahrungen hatte ich schon mal mit `leo.org`. Daher verwende ich `dict.cc` (mir gefällt auch das Interface besser).

Comment: meiner erfahrung nach ist [Pons](http://de.pons.com/) der beste online übersetzer für einzelne wörter.